# Decode Protobuf Text

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, decode

I have some Protobuf text that I'm receiving via an http response from a website. The text roughly looks like this:

```proto
1 {
    2: some value
    7: {
       12: some value
    }
    8: some value
}
```

except the content is much larger. I don't want to paste the actual text for security purposes.

Anyways, how can I "decode" this so that I can see the schemas?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is impossible to obtain a perfectly accurate schema from a protobuf message.

That being said, you can get semi-close. There are some tools like [protobuf-inspector](https://github.com/mildsunrise/protobuf-inspector) that can print out a bit more information about the structure of the message.

Some important caveats about this tool (and in general) as to why it's not possible to obtain the full schema, taken from the README of the tool:

> [...] the field names are obviously lost, together with some high-level details such as:
>
> - whether a varint uses zig-zag encoding or not (will assume no zig-zag by default)
> - whether a 32-bit/64-bit value is an integer or float (both shown by default)
> - signedness (auto-detect by default)